# Make "minimum quantity allowed in shopping cart" an attribute in product edit form

Tags: magento2

I would love to bring "minimum order quantity in shopping cart" (per product) forward from advanced inventory to just below quantity field in product edit form.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add a attribute for minimun qty products.

Secondly, you should capture and validate your minimum qty of product:

- Event: "checkout_cart_product_add_before" validate minimum qty product
- Plugin: beforeupdateItems in class Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart

Hope it will help you :)